# operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<decimal>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this error that I am tying to solve.

Visual Studio 2010 gives the error as:

```
operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<decimal>
```

My Code:

```
// Step 5: Retrieve MPR amount and deduct form Gross Tax Dictionary Per-Employee

                //Query database
                var taxtable = taxTableService.GetAllTaxTables();

                var mprAmount = (from tt in taxtable select tt.U_MPR_amount).Distinct();

                Dictionary<int, decimal> paye = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();

                grossTaxDictionary.ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    var totalPAYE = x.Value - mprAmount;

                    paye.Add(x.Key, totalPAYE);

                });
```

In my database, the field U_MPR_amount is a decimal and so is x.Value.

Error shows up on the line `x.Value - mprAmount;`

What could be the problem? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your code, `mprAmount` is a list, you cannot subtract it from a single value.

If you are certain that the list contains just a single element then you can retrieve it using the `Single` method:

```
var totalPAYE = x.Value - mprAmount.Single();
```

Or, more likely:

```
var mprAmount = (from tt in taxtable select tt.U_MPR_amount).Single();
```

Notice that I’ve changed `Distinct` for `Single`. Using both makes no real sense.

Comment: I think Single is more appropriate than First because it will expose any flaws in OPs assumptions if mprAmount has more than a single value.

Comment: @spender Yup, exactly right. That said, it may well be that multiple values are actually fine and that in such a case only the first is necessary, or that there may be multiple identical values (of which `Distinct` would take care). In both cases `First` *may* be appropriate.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Taxtable stores only one record at a time and did not use single. Thanks a lot Konrad. Solved.